# passport-local's deserializeUser() is not called during deployment. Works fine in development

Tags: reactjs, mern, express-session, passport-local, render.com

(Yes, I know class components are outdated, updating to functional/hooks after successful deployment)

I have implemented a MERN (MongoDB, Express, React, and Node.js) application with authentication using Passport's local strategy and ES6.

**Expected:**
When the user logs in, they send a request to the "/auth/login" route, which is authenticated using the `passport.authenticate()` method. If the authentication is successful, the server sends a "success" response back to the client.

Once the client receives the "success" response, the App.js component's `componentDidMount()` method is called. In this method, the client sends a request to the `"/auth/test"` route to check if the user is authenticated using `req.isAuthenticated()`.

If the user is authenticated, the server sends back the user object, which is then stringified and stored in the client's local storage to indicate that the user is logged in.

**Development Mode:**
For development, I am having the client on one port and the API on another. *Everything works fine*.

**Currently:**
After deployment, I am hosting both the client and API through Render.com.

- I have ensured that all the environment variables are set properly within Render
- I have updated any `baseURL` to match the new client and API URLs respectively as I move away from localhost.
- I have put console.log's everywhere to ensure the flow is as expected (it's not. See below).

**Current Flow:**

- `serializeUser()` is called with the correct id.
- `localStrategy` is called and it finds the correct user and password and returns `done(null, userObj)`.
- `/auth/login` returns the expected status.
- `componentDidMount()` fires in App.js.
- `/auth/test` (in `componentDidMount()`) fires and this is where we check `req.isAuthenticated`.

**Notes on CORS:**

- I am not receiving any errors/warnings about CORS
- I am opting in from the client with `credentials: "include"`
- I am opting in from the server with

  ```js
  const allowedOrigins =
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
      ? "http://localhost:3000"
      : "https://my-client.onrender.com";
  const corsOptions = {
    origin: allowedOrigins,
    credentials: true,
  };
  app.use(cors(corsOptions));
  ```

**Problem:**
`req.isAuthenticated()` returns `false` because `req` is undefined.

**What I've witnessed (through console logs):**

- `deserializeUser()` is never called (Gets called fine in dev)
- Cookies are never set during deployment (Cookie sets fine in dev)
- There are no errors within the API logs
- I get no errors on the console

Thank you

## Client

### `/auth/login`

```js
    const url = baseURL + "/auth/login?username=" + id + "&password=" + pw;
    const res = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: "include",
    });
```

### `/auth/test`

```js
     fetch(baseURL + "/auth/test", {
        credentials: "include",
      })
```

## API

### `/auth/login` Route

```js
authRoute.post("/auth/login",passport.authenticate("local"),
  (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("Login successful");
  },
```

### `/auth/test` Route

```js
authRoute.get("/auth/test", (req, res) => {
  const isAuth = req.isAuthenticated(); // PROBLEM: Returns false because req is undefined
// etc.
```

### passportConfig

```js
  app
    .use(
      session({
        secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie: {
          secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? false : true,
          httpOnly: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? false : true,
          sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "" : "none", // Set if using CORS
          domain: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "" : ".onrender.com",
          path: "/",
          maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 5,
        }, // 5 minutes
      })
    )

    .use(passport.initialize())
    .use(passport.session());
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Jeremiah Have you tried to set saveUnitialized to false? you may not be setting up your session properly print out your req. sessions object see what happens if it has a value you are good there !

Comment: saveUninitialized was indeed intended to be false, thanks for bringing that to my attention. Wesley LeMahieu's answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that looks suspect in your configuration is this line, specifically the `.` preceding your domain:

`domain: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "" : ".onrender.com",` line.

I would drop that line entirely. You could also change it to just `onrender.com`.

Express will also *not set a cookie* if the remote server is passing the request through a non-http intermediary. You can tell it to trust this proxy:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.set('trust proxy', 1);
}
```